# What is Kayakalpa?

Tags: practice, yoga, ayurveda

I would like to understand more about **Kaya Kalpa**, is it some type of Ayurvedic treatment or some sort of yogic practice? What I do understand is that it can actually reverse the physical degeneration caused by age by transforming the old cells to new ones.

If possible I would like to understand the entire procedure with references from the scriptures.

Comment: I can search and give references later but Kayakalpa means = keeping and preventing the death of our cells in our body. Around 90 to 120 days after our body cells will die and fresh cells will form again. But preventing that cells from dying = no death.

Comment: Agastya says don't get cheated in name of Kayakalpa herbs. They're cheat. He says in his song

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kayakalpa is yogic practice but not the Kayakalpa we know in current world. Siddhar Sivavakkiyar describes it in his song.

Urutharitha Nadiyl odingi nindra vaivinai
Karuthinal nirthuye kabalam atre vallirae
Pertharum baalan avar meniyum sivanthu vidum - Sivavakkiyar padal

You can search this song in Sivavakkiyar Siddhar songs

This is song of Sivavakkiyar saying the technique and meaning of Kayakalpa. Kaya = body, Kalpa = immortal. You can live with this body as long as you want here.

He says, there's a Nadi which is inactive near navel. One who can take that Vayu to head, he becomes young and youthful. Even if he's above 60, naturally he will become young if he knows this process.

Comment: This can happen only when the lock between eyebrows is released.

Comment: What exactly is the process? Is it some yoga technique or some ayurvedic treatment?

Comment: Its yoga technique as said above. You need to learn the art of going beyond the external breath. When 9 gates of body is closed = your body turns kayakalpa = young and a victory over death.

Comment: When you utter A U M very slowly = in certain frequency by suspending inhalation and exhalation = your navel goes inside. When navel goes inside, the Vayu is rised. Also Chant Ayyapa SARANAM = in the method they told, your navel goes inside. Chant Govinda namam in certain way, your navel goes inside. Subsquent to that VAYU is taken to head = your external breath stops!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation @akshay ... about the heading not sure how anyone can get rights to edit headings, seems there is a bug in HSE which spammers are aware of!

Comment: My guru's teachings I have explained. When your navel becomes pure and the Vayu is taken to head = only then you can go to Muladhara chakra. When Navel point is cleared = Your past KARMAS are burnt to Ashes.