# Is it possible to change one’s physical features via tapasya/sadhna?

Tags: sadhana

Is it possible to change one’s physical features like height, weight, voice, eye colour etc through a sadhana(s)? What category will such a sadhana fall into,vama margi,or dakshina margi?

Edit: I don’t know of any specific Sadhna/tapasya Kubja did to be healed by Sri Krishna; either way, I wanted to know if such sadhanas exist that give the desired change/(ability to change) instantaneously. Kartivirya Arjuna got his 1000 hands due to the grace of Lord Dattatreya, but then again Lord Dattatreya does not preside over the change of physical features of His devotees? (or does He?)

Comment: Is it okay for you the example of Kubja?

Comment: It is possible. Kartavirya Arjuna can also be an exmaple.

Comment: @hanugm can examples like Kubja and Kārtaviryārjuna who lived in the Dwapara yuga apply to the OP?

Comment: @AravindSuresh Do you mean that the question is asking for personal advice?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to do by exercise, or diet, or a plastic surgeon???

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Yes,but it depends on the trait in question,right,Swamiji?.

Comment: rread how to get astma siddhi from uddhva gita krishna specifies if siddhi is used for personal gain than person doing falls deep pit he is even lesser than normal person spiritually.

Comment: Maybe related check this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29283/11875

Comment: My opinion: a person performing sadhana will not be worried about meaningless things like their skin, height or eyes in the first place. The present body will be lost after death and a new one will be attained anyway. Someone who is attached to this body is not fit for sadhana to begin with.

Comment: @Amethyst Yes it is possible with various Sadhnas. For example as skand Puran mentions an anecdote of a lady  who just by bathing in Tirth in arbuda ranges became as beautiful as thousands of moons. Even Indra tempted for her. But the effect is questionable in Kalyug. For 
 Our hearts are filled with malice. And 
tbh doing such a Sadhana solely is useless and time wasting.

Comment: @AravindSuresh Rightly said..

Comment: @Chamundadas Thanks for the mention..

Comment: Parvati propitiated Brahma to cast off her dark skin. Astavakra mended his twisted body by taking dip into a particular river on the orders of his father. Satyavati's body odour was changed from that of a fish to that of lotuses by the grace of Parashara. Likhita got back his chopped-off arms by taking dip in a river on the orders of Shankha. Indra transformed his thousand vaginas into a thousand eyes.

Comment: Those were the examples of permanent transformations. Temporary transformations are achieved by obtaining siddhis like anima (reducing oneself to atomic level), mahima (enlarging oneself to gigantic proportions), garima (increase one's weight by will), laghima (decrease one's weight by will) & prakamya (to fulfil one's every desire). Perhaps under prakamya comes the power kamarupitva (ability to assume any form at will).

Comment: However I am completely ignorant on how this powers are obtained.

Comment: See story of Chyavana rishi getting young body after helping Ashwins.

Comment: @Kanthri That’s right, forgot about Rishi Chyavan. Good reminder :) There’s also a king who gave his old age to his son or something, and he became a young guy. While his son became suddenly very elder. Can’t remember who it was, I think there’s a topic on it here though.

Comment: This guy ! https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36260/age-swapping-between-humans?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C29.7265 “Transfer thy decrepitude” :D

Comment: Yayati to Puru.

Answer (score -2):

No, it is not possible. Physical features, are a result of prarabdha karma, which can't be changed. One's parents, location of birth, the number of one's siblings etc. are also due to prarabdha Karma and can't be changed through tapasya.

**Theory of Karma**

> Here is a brief summary of the theory of Karma.The Hindu scriptures
> divide a man’s karma into three parts - Prarabdha, Sancita and Agami.
> **Prarabdha Karma is that part of accumulated Karma which has begun to
> bear fruit in the present life. It is a thing which is entirely
> determined, and cannot be avoided. It gives rise to those conditions
> of a man’s existence which he cannot get over however hard he may try.
> We cannot, for existence, get over our sex or parentage or the color
> of our skin in this life. We cannot jump out of our bodies. As far as
> such things are concerned, every one will admit that man is a creature
> of circumstances. Therefore Prarabdha Karma can be exhausted only by
> being experienced.** Sancita Karma is the name given to the accumulated
> karma of all the previous lives of a man. As a result of all his
> actions in the past, he acquires a certain character and certain
> tendencies. These are not unalterable like sex and parentage. It is
> possible to uproot evil habits by persistent effort, and plant good
> ones in their stead. Sancita Karma, unlike Prarabdha, can be expiated
> by penances. And our scriptures say that, unlike Prarabdha it can be
> totally destroyed by Jnana. Lastly, Agami karma is that which is being
> created now in the present life. Its fruits will come to us in a
> future life. It is entirely in our hands. As we sow, so shall we reap.

**A Primer of Hinduism by D. S. Sharma**

I am now adding my response to some objections to the above post.

**Objection 1:**

My point is - nobody can tell that the result of doing X can / cannot be experienced in present lifetime. It is Ishvara's will executed in the form of Karma-phala. In light of this, you may wish to modify your answer accordingly rather than firmly assert in the negative.

**Answer 1:**

I think there is a misunderstanding here. Even if in the rare case that a person is in his last birth even then his physical features can't be changed through tapasya.

**Objection 2:**

But does this mean you cannot work to null the effect of Prarabdh karma?If you are meant to be poor due to your Prarabdh karm,that does not mean the you can’t work to be rich,right? And also in the comments of the question,there were examples of individuals changing their features by certain karma;it may as well be true that they had to face the initial deformity due to Prarabdh karma,but they nulled it by doing certain karm to this end,so I don’t understand how Prarabdh karma is ‘uncorrectable’.

Answer 2:

There is a misunderstanding here. Our mind and it's sanskaras are a result of prarabdha karma. One can indeed change the nature of mind through sadhana. However, it is not possible to change one's physical features, parents, number of siblings, location of birth etc. which are all determined by prarabdha karma.

It has been mentioned that Puranas talk of change in physical features by just bathing. These are simply tales of imagination to generate devotion and should not be taken literally.

Comment: A karma to be performed in the future will become either sanchita or prarabdha after it has been performed right? Therefore it is still possible to attain the fruits of Agami karma in present lifetime.

Comment: It will depend on where exactly is the position of Agami Karma in the list of sancita karmas that is now bearing fruit. In theory it might be possible for a person to get the fruit of agami karma in his present life. In practice it will depend on whether all the sancita karmas have been experienced.

Comment: My point is - nobody can tell that the result of doing X can / cannot be experienced in present lifetime. It is Ishvara's will executed in the form of Karma-phala. In light of this, you may wish to modify your answer accordingly rather than firmly assert in the negative.

Comment: But does this mean you cannot work to null the effect of Prarabdh karma?If you are meant to be poor due to your Prarabdh karm,that does not mean the you can’t work to be rich,right? And also in the comments of the question,there were examples of individuals changing their features by certain karma;it may as well be true that they had to face the initial deformity due to Prarabdh karma,but they nulled it by doing certain karm to this end,so I don’t understand how Prarabdh karma is ‘uncorrectable’.